# TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Index

```
const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const router = require("./config/routes");

    const app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.use(router);

    app.use(4000);
```

controller

```
 const { Time } = require("../models/index");

module.exports = {
  async create(req, res) {
    const time = await Time.create(req.body);
    return res.json(time);
  }
};
```

model

```
    "use strict";

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Time = sequelize.define(
    "Time",
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {}
  );
  return Time;
};
```

Boa noite galera, estou com esse erro TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function, como sempre mas pareceu isso, alguem pode me ajudar, grato.

Comment: Basicamente o `app.use` é uma função que espera uma outra função como parâmetro, o middleware. Logo, você não pode fazer `app.use(4000);`.

Comment: puts,  esse foi de lasca kkk obrigado.

Comment: 4000 era pra ser a porta? Verifica se você não queria chamar o método listen.